# Why does my transformer model have more parameters than the Huggingface implementation?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm loading a GPT model from huggingface as follows:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel, AutoConfig

config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    "gpt2",
    vocab_size=len(tokenizer),
    n_ctx=context_length,
    bos_token_id=tokenizer.bos_token_id,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
)

standard_gpt2 = GPT2LMHeadModel(config).to(device)
standard_gpt2_model_size = sum(t.numel() for t in standard_gpt2.parameters())
print(f"GPT-2 size: {standard_gpt2_model_size/1000**2:.1f}M parameters")
# >>> GPT-2 size: 124.4M parameters
```

If I print the model architecture I get:

```py
GPT2LMHeadModel(
  (transformer): GPT2Model(
    (wte): Embedding(50257, 768)
    (wpe): Embedding(1024, 768)
    (drop): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    (h): ModuleList(
      (0-11): 12 x GPT2Block(
        (ln_1): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): GPT2Attention(
          (c_attn): Conv1D()
          (c_proj): Conv1D()
          (attn_dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          (resid_dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
        (ln_2): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): GPT2MLP(
          (c_fc): Conv1D()
          (c_proj): Conv1D()
          (act): NewGELUActivation()
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
        )
      )
    )
    (ln_f): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  )
  (lm_head): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=50257, bias=False)
)
```

Focusing on the last layer -- `lm_head`, it has `in_features=768, out_features=50257`

So why when I replace just that one layer with the exact same number of parameters I get different results?

```py
standard_gpt2.lm_head = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(in_features = 768, out_features = 50257, bias=False)
)
standard_gpt2_model_size = sum(t.numel() for t in standard_gpt2.parameters())
print(f"GPT-2 size: {standard_gpt2_model_size/1000**2:.1f}M parameters")        
# >>> GPT-2 size: 163.0M parameters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the linear layer of lm_head doesn't have separate weights. It shares its weight tensor with the token embedding layer. You can confirm this with [data-ptr](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.data_ptr.html), which returns the address of the first element of the tensor:

```py
from torch import nn
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel, AutoConfig

model_id = "gpt2"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)

standard_gpt2 = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained(model_id)
standard_gpt2_model_size = sum(t.numel() for t in standard_gpt2.parameters())
print(f"GPT-2 size: {standard_gpt2_model_size} parameters")

print(f"Token embedding layer address {standard_gpt2.transformer.wte.weight.untyped_storage().data_ptr()}")

print(f"LM_head address {standard_gpt2.lm_head.weight.untyped_storage().data_ptr()}")

# Replacing the default head
standard_gpt2.lm_head = nn.Linear(in_features = 768, out_features = 50257, bias=False)
standard_gpt2_model_size = sum(t.numel() for t in standard_gpt2.parameters())
print(f"GPT-2 size after replacing lm_head: {standard_gpt2_model_size} parameters")

print(f"Token embedding layer address after replacing lm_head {standard_gpt2.transformer.wte.weight.untyped_storage().data_ptr()}")

print(f"LM_head address after replacing lm_head {standard_gpt2.lm_head.weight.untyped_storage().data_ptr()}")
```

Output:

```
GPT-2 size: 124439808 parameters
Token embedding layer address: 96251233152832
LM_head address: 96251233152832
GPT-2 size after replacing lm_head: 163037184 parameters
Token embedding layer address after replacing lm_head: 96251233152832
LM_head address after replacing lm_head: 134800505946176
```

I assume you want to keep sharing the weights, in this case, you should call something like this after assigning your new head:

```py
standard_gpt2.lm_head = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(in_features = 768, out_features = 50257, bias=False)
)

standard_gpt2.lm_head[0].weight = standard_gpt2.transformer.wte.weight


standard_gpt2_model_size = sum(t.numel() for t in standard_gpt2.parameters())
print(f"GPT-2 size with tied weights+custom head: {standard_gpt2_model_size} parameters")

print(f"Token embedding layer address with tied weights+custom head: {standard_gpt2.transformer.wte.weight.untyped_storage().data_ptr()}")

print(f"LM_head address with tied weights+custom head: {standard_gpt2.lm_head[0].weight.untyped_storage().data_ptr()}")
```

Output:

```
GPT-2 size: 124439808 parameters
Token embedding layer address 134800505946176
LM_head address 134800505946176
GPT-2 size with tied weights+custom head: 124439808 parameters
Token embedding layer address with tied weights+custom head: 134800505946176
LM_head address with tied weights+custom head: 134800505946176
```

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea. Thanks a lot! My goal is to change the linear layers (MLP) with custom ones. I thought that the head is one of those MLP, but from your explanation it seems like it isn't. Any idea how to access the other MLP layers so I can change them? e.g., with something like, `standard_gpt2.GPT2MLP = nn.Linear(in_features = 768, out_features = 50257, bias=False)`

Comment: As you can see, gpt2 doesn't use any other linear layers (in terms of the pytorch class). They use [Conv1D](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/093848d3ccf3884caf048718b6bae833da0edb94/src/transformers/pytorch_utils.py#L87), which is basically a linear layer, but not exactly the same. You can access those by following the path of the parameters you have printed. For example `standard_gpt2.transformer.h[0].mlp.c_fc`. I don't recommend that. For such a deep modification it is easier and cleaner to write your own class. Feel free to open a separate question in case you need help